# Preinstall a gradle plugin in a Docker image

Tags: docker, gradle

I have a Docker image that does Gradle builds and needs a Gradle plugin.

In my Dockerfile I want to preinstall the Gradle plugin so that when I run my Gradle tasks in the container it does not have to pull down all the Jars every time I have a fresh container.

How can I do this?

The plugin is bmuschko/gradle-docker-plugin

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of preinstalling gradle plugins, but more importantly there is *no need* to do so within or outside docker. All you need to do is to add the plugin to the `buildscript` section of your build as described on the plugin GitHub page: https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-docker-plugin

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.bmuschko:gradle-docker-plugin:X.Y.Z'
    }
}
```

If you mean that you cannot access `jcenter` from within your container and you want to have it statically included into the docker image, just add the jar anywhere in the image during the docker image build step following the `maven` directory structure and change in the above the repository from `jcenter` to `maven { url "file:///reporoot/" }` where `/reporoot` is the root of your "repository" within the container:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url "file:///reporoot/" }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.bmuschko:gradle-docker-plugin:X.Y.Z'
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you able to set some local file locations and other remote options? I may have some downloaded and static and others that get loaded. As long as they don't take too long to pull.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean. The second part of my answer addresses exactly this: providing your artifacts via a local repository within the container

Comment: The gradle-docker-plugin has a number of dependencies. Will it really work to just include the jar for it alone?

Comment: I am afraid you need to get a better general understanding of the problem you want to solve before going to containers, that is how dependency resolution works, how gradle dependency management is organised, what are repository options etc. As you rightly point out, no, it will not be enough, you will need to add all those dependencies in a similar manner. The easiest way to do it is to drop your `~/.gradle` cache, run the build and then check in the cache all the artefacts that have been downloaded and add them to the image in the maven repository structure.

Comment: On the other hand that plugin does not really do much and all it does you could possibly write in a few lines of groovy or Kotlin code directly into the gradle build script thus dropping the need of including the plugin or its dependencies.

Comment: agreed. why use a dependency that you don't need and requires everything under the sun. We don't have Nexus or Artefactory here and it would still be a waste even if we had those.